# Sum of Squares Total (Regression)

Tags: regression, linear-regression

[image]

Just to clarify, does the 2 SST equations only hold true when the data point lies above the regression line? For a data point lying between the regression line and mean, it seems that the formula 
$SST = \sum (Y_i - Y bar)^2$, would not give me results consistent with SST = SSR + SSE...?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the point is above or below the regression line. Because we are squaring, we will only ever be adding non-negative values, with the magnitude of the values only being determined by *distance*, not by whether the point is above or below.

Comment: For the proof that these two formulas for $SST$ are consistent see [Partition of Sum of Squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_sums_of_squares)

Comment: @WaveX I'm still new to this so I'm not looking for rigorous proof, just trying to understand it. For a datapoint that lies between the regression line and the mean, SSR = (y hat - y bar)^2, which should be the longest distance. Yet SST = SSR + SSE which would imply that is it longer than the SSR. How can that be possible if SST is calculated by taking (actual value of y - y bar)^2?? It sits below the regression line so SST should be smaller than SSR, isn't it?

Comment: For an individual data point, what we have going on is that $$y - \bar{y} =  (\hat{y}-\bar{y}) + (y - \hat{y})$$ so in the situation you are describing, the $(y-\hat{y})$ part is actually negative, so the distance from the regression line to the mean is indeed the longest but the algebra still holds true